# Draw Venn diagram considering a specific treshold in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, plot, venn-diagram

I have a DataFrame `df1` and I want to make a pairwise Venn diagram.
I want to show the number of overlap of the `ENSG`s (which should be defined by the treshold Cor > 0.1) from `Cor1` and `Cor2`.

```
df1 <- structure(list(ENSG = c("ENSG89306", "ENSG230107", 
"ENSG128274", "ENSG100266", "ENSG100300", "ENSG100290", 
"ENSG100347", "ENSG261251", "ENSG138964", "ENSG93000", 
"ENSG226328", "ENSG100376", "ENSG205643", "ENSG128408", 
"ENSG77935", "ENSG130638", "ENSG241990", "ENSG75234", 
"ENSG260708", "ENSG54611", "ENSG0128159", "ENSG188511", 
"ENSG212939", "ENSG100258", "ENSG235111", "ENSG184164", 
"ENSG79974", "ENSG170638", "ENSG73169", "ENSG100427"), Cor1 = c(0.143714860528127, 0.140903769519937, 
                                 0.220285794778746, -0.0764275174733086, 0.189080738386014, 0.303454798874576, 
                                 0.268021621489439, 0.160662468776058, 0.0797970266014118, 0.0303382173551934, 
                                 0.0113128251324056, 0.139860538051072, 0.018553280666828, 0.219125961518781, 
                                 0.0898644147097944, 0.0595462431532415, 0.0161782451465834, 0.0633049687607816, 
                                 0.0774210516121433, 0.548879883295163, 0.133707267647068, -0.0275291634151178, 
                                 0.0132847938530041, -0.0468134127145183, 0.212056295268778, 0.169525452308467, 
                                 0.223304209279054, 0.0554950703076702, 0.268747518524584, 0.210788129456603), 
Cor2 = c(-0.0567563530541253, 0.1467342043789, -0.00462978967736684, -0.0949858201084905, -0.0128046412985325, 0.308707458359154, 
               -0.0288326568108287, 0.123139258225873, 0.127834335556582, 0.0476613529381162, 
               0.108169226237846, 0.135726417808339, -0.0499017880297932, 0.269937039031533, 
               0.124331777264371, -0.00443812208979526, 0.0531319792200424, 
               0.0639288256005855, 0.188225249289256, 0.471541813383384, 0.116236004671794, 
               0.0197695247788121, 0.0476613529381162, -0.0501695121118335, 
               0.194805149886956, 0.148499060471642, 0.263555546219041, 0.0374697142901511, 
               0.213968479801099, 0.00159814317995886)), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

I do appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you want.  Can you explain what you mean by overlaps?  For example, does `ENSG89306` overlap with any of the other ENSGs? If so, how?  What is the meaning of the columns `Cor1` and `Cor2`?

Comment: I meant how many ENSGs captured respecting the treshold from Cor1 and from Cor2. It is supposed to be a pairwise venn diagram including two circles which show the number of ENSGs that captures by both Cor1 and Cor2 (overlapped = in common) and how many by each separately (not in common). am I clear explaining it?

Comment: So if Cor1 and Cor2 are both >0.1 for a row, then this ENSG should be in the overlap? If only Cor1>0.1, then in the Cor1 only part of the diagram, and if only Cor2>0.1, then in the Cor2-only part of the diagram?   And if both are <=0.1, don't count at all?

Comment: Presicely what it is sepposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you mean to do something like this, leveraging the `ggvenn` package?.  `mutate(across())` here converts `Cor1` and `Cor2` columns into logical columns; these can be directly fed to `ggvenn`, and the overlap region is the number of rows where all (in this case "both") logical vectors are TRUE.

```
library(dplyr); library(ggvenn)

df1 %>%
  mutate(across(Cor1:Cor2, ~(.x>0.1))) %>% 
  ggvenn(c("Cor1", "Cor2"))
```

[image: venn_diagram]